# Input numbers in a vector in C++ without any limit

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Input numbers in a vector in C++ without any limit.When user press enter instead of a number it should print all the numbers inputted till now.

```
vector <int> numbers;
vector <int>::iterator i;
int num;
while(cin>>num && isdigit(num))
    numbers.push_back(num);

for(i=numbers.begin();i!=numbers.end();++i)
{
    cout<<*i<<'\n';
}
```

I am doing this thing but as soon as user press enter after taking suppose n numbers it exits the program w/o going to the printing loop.

Comment: Try i++ instead of ++i?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) you see that it accepts a character.

Your input is an int.

`isdigit` checks to see if your `num` is in the range '0' (48) to '9' (57).

The isdigit call is entirely unnecessary.

Your program will work as it is if you input 49 50 51 52 [Return][Ctrl + D] or whatever you shell deems end of input. Or if you want `cin>>num` to fail, just input 51 52 53 acbd(not parseable as an int)[Return].

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, Your approach to read multiple numbers will need a different implementation.

Using `cin >> num`  reads a single integer & press Enter to allow the buffer to be saved as int in `num`.So you will have to press Enter for every number.

But `isdigit(num)` fails and kills the while loop. Infact , `isdigit` is poorly used.

Why would you want to check `int` is a number or not.

`isdigit` takes a char type converts to int & find it falls in  ASCII range of digits 48 to 57  ( 0,... 9 )

Proper use of `isdigit` is

```
char ch1 = '5';
char ch2 = 'a';
isdigit (ch1) // true
isdigit (ch2) // false
```

Remove isdigit () check on int which is pointless.

Now that the while loop depends only on `cin>>num` , you don't have any termination condition.

Possible approach would be to read multiple numbers could be read space delimited integers and convert into array , if the list of numbers are small enough.

Otherwise , read from File Stream or change the design of reading multiple numbers which relies on single enter to be pressed.

Answer (score 0):

As mention by other `isdigit` will not serve your purpose.
You need to check length of input line. If length is zero then user pressed entered, otherwise something which need to converter to integer.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RzwLU94id5bwWaFa)